# Can I use multiple selector where $(document).on() concept used

Tags: jquery

I need to know this concept.
Here I have written the code in jQuery to use multiple selector. Is this syntax correct or any suggestion.

```
$(document).on('click','.selector1, .selector2',function(){alert(111)});
```

Comment: __Yes__, You can and syntax is __correct__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. This code will help you to understand it better

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></scrpt>
</head>
<body>

</script>
<p class="selector1">Selector 1</p>
<p class="selector2">Selector 2</p>

<script>
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','.selector1, .selector2',function(){alert(111)});
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine. May be some issues were there on that. But now looking the code is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.selectorname1, .selectorname2').on('click', some_function);
```

another method is there

```
$('.selectorname1').add('.selectorname2').on('click', some_function);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: These are actually different approach. OP's using event delegation while this applying listener to belonging DOM directly.